# Teamsite validation rule to allow two fields or none, but not only one

Tags: xml, xslt, teamsite

I am creating a datacapture.cfg file, and have defined two fields as not required, but I really want to make a rule to state that if one is defined, the other must be defined too.

How can I define validation rules in teamsite for multi-part fields?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as XSLT, I assume that you can validate using XSLT? If so, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="field1[not(../field2)] | field2[not(../field1)]">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Both fields must be defined</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field1 | field2">
    <!-- do whatever you want to do if both are defined -->
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes that somewhere in your code you apply templates to those fields. Otherwise, you can also wrap this into an `xsl:if`. It also assumes that those fields are XML elements, if they are attributes, change them to `@field1` and `@field2` and make sure you also apply templates to the attributes.